# set object style with basil.js

Tags: adobe-indesign, basil.js

from basil cheatsheet:

```
b.objectStyle(”myStyle”); // return or create style with given name
```

But when I try it (on a text frame):

```
b.selection().appliedObjectStyle =  b.objectStyle("CAPTION");
```

Nothing happens.
While this works:

```
b.selection().appliedObjectStyle = app.documents[0].objectStyles.item("CAPTION");
```

So what is a good use of the 'b.objectStyle("CAPTION");' method apart from creating a object style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You discovered a bug in basil.js 1.08. This will be fixed in the next version.

Please use b.doc().objectStyles.item("CAPTION"); until then. That also goes for

b.characterStyle(); and b.paragraphStyle(); unfortunately. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, on the side, is `b.doc()` prefered over `app.documents[0]`?

Comment: yes, it is. it's doing some internal organisation and might be even more important in future... so if you use basil.js in your project you should try to stick to our conventions in order to avoid other things to fail. but of course it's thinkable to mix approaches.